# Cast dataSnapshot from Firebase to Integer failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to extract a Integer called scoreBase from a realtime Firebase database. I want to read data from the databse, not to listen for changes, thats why I'm using  mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent. I don't understand how to cast it to an Integer though and I get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
>           at com.example.root.exercicis.Signin$2$1.onDataChange(Signin.java:131)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:183)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:75)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:63)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:55)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

**This is the code:**

```
 public void onLogin(View view) {
    email = userEditText.getText().toString();
    password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
           @Override
              public void onComplete (@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {
                  if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                     // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                      FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                      mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid()).child("score");
                      mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                              int scoreBase = (int) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                              Toast.makeText(Signin.this, Integer.toString(scoreBase), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("SuperScore", scoreBase).apply();
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                          }
                      });

                      updateUI(user);
                  } else {
                      // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                      Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "Authentication failed.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     updateUI(null);
        }

        // ...
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution replacing

```
int scoreBase = (int) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

for

```
int scoreBase = (int) dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
```

Comment: That is indeed the proper way to get an integer value from the snapshot. I usually stick to only using `Long` in my Java code for values that come from Firebase though, since that's the best reflection of the underlying type in the database.

Answer (score 3):

From Docs of [DataSnapShot.getValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue()), getValue() return Object which can only be casted to Boolean, String, Long, Double, Map, List (Not Integer). In line

```
 int scoreBase = (int) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

You're casting it directly to int which is causing Casting Exception.
You first need to cast it to Long and then to int like:

```
int scoreBase = (int) ((long) dataSnapshot.getValue());
```

or you can also use :

```
int scoreBase = (int) dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
```

You can read documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot).

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether the object is null or not.

You can also try.

```
Integer.ValueOf(dataSnapShot.getValue());
```